# import a fusiontable using importTable() in google-api-php-client

Tags: php, google-maps, google-api, google-fusion-tables, google-api-php-client

I'd like to import a Google Fusion Table programmatically using Google's API PHP client library which can be found on GitHub https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. It contains a service class Fusiontables.php which has a function importTable() that obviously could do what I like.

```
/**
* Imports a new table. (table.importTable)
*
* @param string $name The name to be assigned to the new table.
* @param array $optParams Optional parameters.
*
* @opt_param string delimiter The delimiter used to separate cell values. This
* can only consist of a single character. Default is ,.
* @opt_param string encoding The encoding of the content. Default is UTF-8. Use
* auto-detect if you are unsure of the encoding.
* @return Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table
*/
public function importTable($name, $optParams = array())
{
  $params = array('name' => $name);
  $params = array_merge($params, $optParams);
  return $this->call('importTable', array($params), "Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table");
}
```

The function reads simple enough though I can't figure out how to feed it with the actual data, perhaps to be taken from a CSV file.

I've found a late answer about another function importRows() here [Google PHP API Client & Fusion Tables: How to use importRows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740987/google-php-api-client-fusion-tables-how-to-use-importrows). It explains to use the optParams array key 'data' to insert the actual data as a comma separated list. 
First, all the used parameters are not described in the function's comment, so where to find a good documentation? 
Second, I'm not clear about how to specify data consisting of several rows (as the function name reads 'rows' in plural).

Hoping to find some expert about this Google API PHP client library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google PHP API Client & Fusion Tables: How to use importRows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740987/google-php-api-client-fusion-tables-how-to-use-importrows)

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a question which i already refered to in my question because it is not a duplicate (importTable vs. importRows) and the answer to the other question was not clear/complete enough for me.

Comment: Why is this tagged [google-maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps)? Doesn't seem to have anything to do with maps.

Comment: Because I will use the Fusiontable to display a huge amount of locations in a Google Map and developers with knowlegde of Google Maps might certainly have experience with Fusiontables as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. ["Standard parameters"](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/standard_parameters) for the PHP functions are not detailed on the relevant [PHP client function method](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table_Resource.html#_importTable).
2. The general format of the data imported for `importRows` is CSV. So to specify multiple rows, rows in the input blob should be separated by the appropriate newline character.