# Insert more than one record into a table

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-fusion-tables

I am currently following the steps of the [official api source.](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts)

And in the current state of the project, I am getting information from the table, changing and inserting data, without any errors.

However I would like to do a bulk insert in my table.

It's my code:

```
$array = array();
foreach ($objects as $object) {
    array_push(
        $array,
        "('".$object->lat.",".$object->lng."','".$object->other->lat.",".$object->other->lng."')"
    );
}
$values = implode(",", $array);
$client = new Google_Client();
$tableId = "TableId";
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
$service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);

$service->query->sql("INSERT INTO ".$tableId." ('Location', 'City Location') VALUES ".$values); // I'm sorry, I forgot.
```

When I try to enter a record without using the same code, it works

This is my `sql` variable when you have more than one record:

```
INSERT INTO TableId 
('Location', 'City Location') 
VALUES 
('88.064342,-50.280747','-8.77,-36.62'),
(-55.781345,-69.294770','-28.24,-48.67'),
('14.696452,-26.844802','-19.92,-43.17')
```

The api returns the following error:

```
{  
  "error":{  
    "errors":[  
      {  
        "domain":"fusiontables",
        "reason":"badQueryCouldNotParse",
        "message":"Invalid query: Parse error near ',' (line 1, position 92).",
        "locationType":"parameter",
        "location":"q"
      }
    ],
    "code":400,
    "message":"Invalid query: Parse error near ',' (line 1, position 92)."
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how the `$service` sends the `$values`, aka what's the method on that object that actually sends the data? That part is missing

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot. `$service->query->sql("INSERT INTO ".$tableId." ('Location', 'City Location') VALUES ".$values);`

Updated ask

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add multiple rows with a single INSERT statement - you need to use one statement per set of values. For a bulk insert, you probably want to use [`importRows`](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/importRows) rather than [multiple INSERT statements](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#insertRow), as it is generally faster, more reliable, and also consumes less quota.

[PHP API doc for importRows](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table_Resource.html#_importRows)
If you go the `importRows` route, take note of the [standard parameters](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/standard_parameters) as you will pass the new rows in this manner. Related questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740987/google-php-api-client-fusion-tables-how-to-use-importrows) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897888/how-i-can-use-importrows-fusion-data-table-in-my-project?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is less of a Google Service problem and more of how your end query string is formatted. You likely have a quote missing or a parentheses missing.

```
// Flatten the array of objects into values per entry
$location_values = array_map($objects, function($object) {
    [
         $object->lat,
         $object->lng,
         $object->other->lat,
         $object->other->lng,
    ];
}

// $location_values will be a multidimensional array, we need to turn it to a string
$location_values_stringified = array_reduce($location_values, function($final_string, $location) {
    // to turn an array into a string
   $location_string = implode($location, ',');
   // wrap the string in parenthesis
   $location_string = sprintf('(%s)', $location_string);
   return $final_string . ',' . $location_string;
}, '');

// build query string
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO %s ('Location', 'City Location') VALUES %s", $tableId, $location_values_stringified);
```

I haven't actually executed this in PHP, so there might be a syntax error or 2 but that *should* get you a resemblance of the format you need:

```
INSERT INTO TableId 
('Location', 'City Location') 
VALUES 
('88.064342,-50.280747','-8.77,-36.62'),
(-55.781345,-69.294770','-28.24,-48.67'),
('14.696452,-26.844802','-19.92,-43.17')
```

If you need to check your `$query`, use `die(var_dump($query));` right before you send it over to `$service`. Good luck.

Comment: I found [this doc](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#insertRow), apparently the way a query should be sent is different.