# How i can use importRows Fusion Data Table in my project?

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-fusion-tables

I have this code:

```
    $out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    fputcsv($out, 
        array('Location')
    );
    foreach($objects as $object){
        fputcsv($out, 
            array(
                $ad->objectLat.",".$ad->objectLnt,
            )
        );
    }
    $test = fclose($out);

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables');
    $service = new Google_Service_Fusiontables($client);
    $service->table->importRows($test);
```

I looked in the documentation, but could not find the reference

Answer (score 0):

Given that the PHP library's documentation does not identify how the to-be-imported data is passed, it likely uses a [standard parameter](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/guide/standard_parameters).

Some documentation links:
[REST API](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/reference/table/importRows), [examples](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/using#ImportingRowsIntoTables)
[PHP API Client Library](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/fusiontables/v2/php/latest/class-Google_Service_Fusiontables_Table_Resource.html#_importRows)